# Library to detect and parse browser information

Tags: user-agent, browser-detection, wurfl

I have a requirement where I need to store various bits of browser information such as Brand (eg IE, Chrome..), Model (eg IE, Chrome), Browser Version (eg 7.0.0.0),  OS Version (eg Windows 7, OSX, Linux), Flash version info ect.  For mobile detection, I'm using WURFL which uses the user agent string and has great support for mobile devices, but not so much for desktop web browsers.  I'm using the web patch with WURFL, but to make it useful I would have to add my own override patch to provide some of the items listed above.  Is this the best way to do this?  Or has anyone found a library out there more suited to this kind of task.  If WURFL is the best way to do this, is there an updated and maintained web patch that's more comprehensive than the one provided on the WURFL site?

Answer (score 0):

Based on information received directly from ScientiaMobile the next minor release (estimated at a couple of weeks from the date of this post) of the API will improve the quality of web browser detection and that they are considering including the web patch within the main repository removing the need for a separate patch file.